# API Google Drive PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Estou utilizando o Google Drive para subir arquivos via php, com a API que eles disponibilizam, porém, [a library que o Google passa](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/downloads) solicita um arquivo que não existe nessa library que nos é fornecido.

Segui [todos os procedimentos](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php) como informam,porém no momento dos testes ele faz um `require("Google/Google_cliente.php')`, mas o arquivo não existe.

Alguém já utilizou essa API?
Conseguem me informar onde consigo este arquivo?

Comment: Coloca seu projeto junto dessa api: https://github.com/eduardocasas/Google-Drive-PHP-API-Simple-App-Example Troca os requires por: require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nos links que você postou, existe um link para a documentação da API do Google em PHP. A lib que você procura, em sua última versão, está **[aqui](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-php-client-0.6.7.tar.gz)**.

Depois é só descompactar a biblioteca e usá-la no seu projeto.

Só mais um detalhe: o caminho correto do Client é `src/Google/Google_Client.php`. Pode ser também que seja apenas um erro de digitação.

Comment: Então @Rodrigo Rigotti ele faz o require no caminho que você mencionou, porém, em outro momento ele também faz um require no caminho 'Google/Client.php', assim como outros arquivos no mesmo caminho.

Irei fazer os testes hoje e informarei sobre mais detalhes.